# How to pass a two argument to a custom filter in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a custom filter in angular js  in that how to pass a two arguments in angularjs or other its possible to use a $scope and $rootScope inside  a filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this, I tried its working fine for me:

```
 <p>{{mytext | customfilter:arg1}}</p>
```

Comment: How to pass more than 1 in html ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass $scope as an argument to filter.

```
app.filter('filterReceiptsForDate', function () {
  return function (input, scope) {
    return input + ' <strong>' + scope.var2 + '</strong>';
  };
});
```

in HTML

```
<div ng-bind="var1 | filterReceiptsForDate:this"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.filter("myFilter", function () {
        return function (myValue, arg0, arg1) {
            var retValue = myValue; // and do something width arg0 and arg2
            return retValue;
        }
    })
```

hope this code snippet helps.

Comment: in html how can i pass that mean <p>{{ mytext | customfilter}}</p> u got it

Comment: {{ mytext | customfilter:1:2}}